# What hood for this bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, brake-levers

After 8 years; the hood of my brake levers is in pretty bad shape.
The bike is (I think) a Bruno 700c TOUR SOLO 2012

[image]

I'd like to replace the hood; but I have no idea what model to buy.

Any idea ?

Comment: Brake lever hoods are as many as makes and types of levers. That should be your starting point. Remove the hood and identify the brake. Although a pair of standard levers might well be in the similar price range than new hoods. (Sadly!)

Comment: The only problem is considering the state of the hood, removing them equals destroying them ...

Comment: The lever in the picture looks like the design is based on 2000s Campagnolo Ergopower levers, also known as "round ergo". The hood itself is made of flexible rubber, so I would expect any hood made for the original Ergos or one of the non-shifter copies to either fit directly or be modifiable to fit.

Comment: @Antzi: You can almost be sure of that. :-(

Comment: @ojs: The problem will however be the underlying shape of the mechanical part. Looking 'like' Campa my hide a completely different built. They also look like Diacompe, but the best procedure would be to find a LBS that has a wide range of hoods. Some but not all may have.

Comment: I'm not sure how different the underlying structure can be. After all, the hood is only a thin rubber sheath and to support it, the lever body can't have radically different shape. The tabs that hold the rubber in place may be different, but they aren't critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Tektro RL340, or the same lever under another name. Cane Creek SCR-5 hoods are the readily obtainable option. Tektro made variants of this lever for a bunch of brands, including their own, but the Cane Creek hoods work for all.

Comment: Looks like it ! I bought a new hood; will accept tomorrow if it fits :)

Comment: It's a bit weird, it's slightly too large for the front part, but otherwise seems to be the correct model :/

Comment: Like the new hood is fitting loose in front?

Comment: Yes, exactly ...

Comment: There's a kind of lip and groove interface. Have you tried pressing the lip in tightly into the groove? Also, putting them on, use alcohol all over everything to lubricate it and it should slide on. Don't use lots of force.

Comment: It's really too big. I think the packet I got from amazon was a return (had signs of having been opened). I'll bought the same from a different vendor and will return these. Let's see tomorrow :)